# How can i create a Bootstrap like 12 column ( only grid ) grid system using new CSS GRID Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, flexbox, css-grid

How can I create a bootstrap-like 12 column grid using the new CSS GRID technology? Can anybody please show me a demo how to do it? I am really getting confused with this new technology. I want to make a simple 12 column grid-like bootstrap using CSS grid. What my approach should be for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`display:grid;` allows you to create columns and also rows.

You need to define a grid of 12 columns and set up classes to span so many rows and so many columns, so alike bootsrap classes you can size your element within from 1th to 12th bits of a row, but , unlike bootstrap, it allows you also to span element through rows without extra markup/inbrication:

example:https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RLjdrM

```css
.grid {
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid lightgray;
  background: lightgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  counter-reset: div;
}

.grid div {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid div:before {
  counter-increment: div;
  content: 'N°' counter(div);
}

.grid div[class]:after {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  content: "Class applied : "attr(class);
  color: crimson;
}


/* spanning cols, complete values missing */

.col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
}

.col-3 {
  grid-column: auto/span 3;
}

.col-6 {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}

.col-8 {
  grid-column: auto/span 8;
}


/* spanning rows , complete values missing*/

.row-2 {
  grid-row: auto/span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-2 row-2"></div>
  <div class="col-8"></div>
  <div class="col-2 row-2"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Here is 2 usefull link to start playing with CSS grids layout :

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Answer (score 1):

Well it is really easy: define 13 vertical lines with the same distance to each other. Since one is always (and has to be) there, you will only have to create 12 lines with an relative distance to their previous lines) Like this:

```css
/* actual grid code */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); /* This creates 12 equally width columns */
  /* Note that one line (the outer left one) is always there → only 12 have to be created */
}


/* For this demo only */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.showcase {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.r1 {grid-column: 1 / 2}
.r2 {grid-column: 2 / 3}
.r3 {grid-column: 3 / 4}
.r4 {grid-column: 4 / 5}
.r5 {grid-column: 5 / 6}
.r6 {grid-column: 6 / 7}
.r7 {grid-column: 7 / 8}
.r8 {grid-column: 8 / 9}
.r9 {grid-column: 9 / 10}
.r10 {grid-column: 10/ 11}
.r11 {grid-column: 11/ 12}
.r12 {grid-column: 12/ 13}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  <!-- You can change the width and hight here. Bootstrap uses a max-width to make it look better on bigger screens -->
  
  <div class="showcase r1">1</div>
  <div class="showcase r2">2</div>
  <div class="showcase r3">3</div>
  <div class="showcase r4">4</div>
  <div class="showcase r5">5</div>
  <div class="showcase r6">6</div>
  <div class="showcase r7">7</div>
  <div class="showcase r8">8</div>
  <div class="showcase r9">9</div>
  <div class="showcase r10">10</div>
  <div class="showcase r11">11</div>
  <div class="showcase r12">12</div>
  
</div>
```

Note, however, that the css-grid is far more powerful than the bootstrap grid, so make sure to use it to its fullest potential. F.e.  `grid-template-area` is really useful. As is naming the columns/rows. (and of course the addition of rows itself is pretty powerful)

You can find a pretty good overview/tutorial here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *flexbox* layout instead.

For that, you create a `div` which you want the flexbox to be inside:

```
<div class="flex-menu">
   <a>Item 1</a>
   <a>Item 2</a>
   <a>Item 3</a>
</div>
```

In CSS, set the `display` parameter as `flex`:

```
.flex-menu {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

Only one html tag nested to the main `div` is shown per column.

If you don't explicitly say the items positions, the positions will be assigned in the code order. The flexbox menu will look like that:

**Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3**

Comment: how flex-direction:column is going to draw 12 columns ?  If you set your <a> into block, you do not need any reset on display for the flex-menu ... At least, the question deserved this answer :))

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyr! I used `columns` instead of `row`. This way, the items would show one under the other, not side by side. Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

It would like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;

}
.one {
  grid-column: 1 ;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two { 
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 ;
}
.three {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 ;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.five {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.six {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.eight {
  grid-column: 8;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.nine {
  grid-column: 9;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.ten {
  grid-column: 10;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.eleven {
  grid-column: 11;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.twelve {
  grid-column: 12;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="eight">Eight</div>
  <div class="nine">Nine</div>
  <div class="ten">Ten</div>
  <div class="eleven">Eleven</div>
  <div class="twelve">Twelve</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the grid has a "grid-row", so it's not going to wrap like Bootstrap with this particular code. I referenced https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout if you need to see more details of it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some makeup to the @G-Cyrillus answer, the accepted answer.

If you would like your columns to be full width at a certain screen sizes for better user experience, then add this at the bottom of the CSS file:

```
/* Full Width below 768 pixels */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12{
     grid-column: auto/span 12;
  }
}
```

So Your full code should look like this:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid lightgray;
  background: lightgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  counter-reset: div;
}

.grid div {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid div:before {
  counter-increment: div;
  content: 'N°' counter(div);
}

.grid div[class]:after {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  content: "Class applied : "attr(class);
  color: crimson;
}


/* spanning cols, complete values missing */

.col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
}

.col-3 {
  grid-column: auto/span 3;
}

.col-6 {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}

.col-8 {
  grid-column: auto/span 8;
}


/* spanning rows , complete values missing*/

.row-2 {
  grid-row: auto/span 2;
}

/* Full Width below 768 pixels */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12{
     grid-column: auto/span 12;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-2 row-2"></div>
  <div class="col-8"></div>
  <div class="col-2 row-2"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```